Can you cook with castor oil?
I'm seeing castor oil as a cooking oil in my local INDO-PAK shop and was wondering how good of an idea that is? Will castor oil impart flavour or is it more of a neutral oil? I know my mother would dry heave at the idea of using castor oil in cooking, as she was given it in a manner that liquid paraffin is used as a child.
MOTIVATION:

There was a long comment thread of opinions that it isn't a cooking oil; I'm deleting these all, including my own, as being an attempt to answer. Please note that "it is a laxative" is not the same as "it is not a food" - prunes are both a laxative and a food, for example. I'd really like to see well-sourced answers here, based on something other than 'it has other uses, so it's probably sold for them'.

Someone has simply mis-labeled this, putting an oil with other oils. Castor oil is not a cooking oil, its used as a constipation remedy and some people use it on their skin as a moisturizer. Flavor-wise, the oil in its unrefined form has been described as having an acrid taste, refined oil has been described as having a neutral flavor, some say it has a very unpleasant, nauseating aftertaste. It's consistency is similar to runny petroleum jelly.  Sounds absolutely yummy-nummy!
I found from reading more about it that parents used to feed castor oil to children as a punishment because it tasted so awful, and it was force-fed to people in the past as a form of torture because even moderate doses can cause violent diarrhea.
So, using it as a cooking oil is a Bad Idea ™

Do not consume castor oil;  is not a cooking oil. It is used to make a range of cosmetics, candles and other non-cooking items; as well as being an excellent lubricant (an early use was to lubricate castors, hence the name). Why this shop is selling it is up to them, but I suspect, not as a food.
The seeds of the plant genus (Ricinus) from which the oil is extracted are highly toxic, containing the lectin known as Ricin; famously used in the assassination of Georgi Markov. This toxin is largely deactivated by the heating process used for the oil extraction, but the oil still has a major component Ricinoleic acid, which has a dramatic laxative effect, causing violent diarrhea.
